# Error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 with classes

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and writing a program for fun that helps me diet. This program isn't done but compiling as I write. I keep getting the error mentioned in the title:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 with classes

I've looked at similar questions but they all have to do with templates and inherited classes which is different than my scenario. I'm just declaring a class, nothing fancy. I think it has to do with the class not being defined properly but I can't figure out what it is. It might be something dumb I'm missing but I'm still stuck. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Meal
{
private:
    string name;
int protein;
int carbs;
int fat;
int calories;

public:
 Meal(string name, int calories, int protein, int carbs, int fat);

};



int main()
{
int calories = 0;
int rest_or_lift;
int create_or_not;
cout << "Enter 1 if it is a workout day, enter 2 if it is a rest day./n";
cin >> rest_or_lift;
if (rest_or_lift == 1)
{
    calories = 2554;
}
else if (rest_or_lift == 2)
{
    calories = 1703;
}

cout << "Enter 1 to input existing foods, enter 2 to create new foods./n";
cin >> create_or_not;
if (create_or_not == 1)
{
    cout << "This aspect has not yet been created /n"; //need to fix this part
}
else if (create_or_not == 2)
{
    do 
    {   
        string name;
        int protein;
        int carbs;
        int fat;
        int calories;
        cout << "Enter the name of the food./n";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter how many calories the food has. /n";
        cin >> calories;
        cout << "Enter how many grams of protein the food has /n";
        cin >> protein;
        cout << "Enter how many grams of carbs the food has /n";
        cin >> carbs;
        cout << "Enter how many grams of fats the food has /n";
        cin >> fat;
        Meal(name, calories, protein, carbs, fat);
        cout << "Enter another food? Enter 1 to exit, 2 to continue.";
        cin >> create_or_not;
    } while (create_or_not == 2);

}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try to use full sentences when you ask questions, that makes the text better readable. See also [How to ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Spontifixus: "better readable" ironic

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're right here. I used a UserScript providing automated comments for review tasks - and didn't review the comment text the UserScript provided... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no constructor for class `Meal`. You can solve it e.g. like this:

```
class Meal
{
private:
  string m_name;
  int m_protein;
  int m_carbs;
  int m_fat;
  int m_calories;

public:
  Meal(string name, int calories, int protein, int carbs, int fat)
    : m_name(name), m_protein(protein),
      m_carbs(carbs), m_fat(fat), m_calories(calories)
  {
  }
};
```